# How to find return for each month from daily prices, when having multiple NaN in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset, two years of prices for fifteen funds. I want to find the returns of all the funds for each months. Few funds update their prices irregularly so some columns have many NaN data. I don’t want to drop all the rows with nan values, is there anyway to just ignore NaNs when calculating returns.
so it is 2 questions
1.Can we just ignore the NaN items
2.How to compute the returns for each months of Year

this is a sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
prices = pd.DataFrame({"Date":['1926-07-01', '1926-07-02', '1926-07-03', '1926-08-01',
               '1926-08-01', '1926-08-02', '1927-08-03', '1927-08-04',
               '1927-08-05'],
             “fund_1": [8.70, 11.08, 10.71, 11.59, 8.73, np.nan, 8.71, np.nan, 8.73],
             “fund_2": [10.66, 8.91, 8.71, 8.43, 8.73, 11.08, 10.71, 11.59, 12.11]})


prices = prices.set_index('Date’)

           fund_1   fund_2
Date        
1926-07-01  8.70    10.66
1926-07-02  11.08   8.91
1926-07-03  10.71   8.71
1926-08-01  11.59   8.43
1926-08-01  8.73    8.73
1926-08-02  NaN    11.08
1927-08-03  8.71   10.71
1927-08-04  NaN    11.59
1927-08-05  8.73   12.11
```

I’ve tried like bellow, but it is not working

```
prices.fillna(0)

montly_returns = prices.groupby(prices.index.year, prices.index.month).apply(prices.pct_change()+1.prod() - 1)
```

I need some advices

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need an actual `DatetimeIndex`, currently your code only sets the index to be the date column but it never converts it to datetimes.

```
prices = pd.DataFrame(...)

prices["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(prices["Date"])
prices = prices.set_index("Date")
prices
>>>
            fund_1  fund_2
Date                      
1926-07-01    8.70   10.66
1926-07-02   11.08    8.91
1926-07-03   10.71    8.71
1926-08-01   11.59    8.43
1926-08-01    8.73    8.73
1926-08-02     NaN   11.08
1927-08-03    8.71   10.71
1927-08-04     NaN   11.59
1927-08-05    8.73   12.11
```

Also, when grouping, you should put it in a list:

```
grp = prices.groupby([prices.index.year, prices.index.month])
```

Furhtermore, you can just use [.pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html?highlight=pct_change#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change) instead of apply which is also much faster.

```
grp.pct_change()
              fund_1    fund_2
Date                          
1926-07-01       NaN       NaN
1926-07-02  0.273563 -0.164165
1926-07-03 -0.033394 -0.022447
1926-08-01       NaN       NaN
1926-08-01 -0.246764  0.035587
1926-08-02  0.000000  0.269187
1927-08-03       NaN       NaN
1927-08-04  0.000000  0.082166
1927-08-05  0.002296  0.044866
```

To answer your questions:

Q2. You can calculate the returns the way I demonstrated (I am not sure what exactly this: `prices.pct_change()+1.prod() - 1` was supposed to do in your call to .apply but pct_change is all you need to get the returns)

Q1.

You will need to play around with different replacements for the None values to see what is best for you. As you can see, I just left the none values as they are, which makes the rows 0.0000.

This is my preference, and you can just replace the 0.0000s with None afterwards, if you want to. 
But be careful with inserting numbers before calculating, since pandas will use them in the calculation and it may mess with the results.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#calculations-with-missing-data) is some more information on how pandas handles missing values when performing calculations.

(The reason that every group starts with NaN is because the first row has no preceeding value to calculate the difference from.)